# Virtual directory not getting created in MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am following [this](https://youtu.be/KvTy_FAYjks?list=PL6n9fhu94yhVm6S8I2xd6nYz2ZORd7X2v) link to create a simple MVC app. And he mentions that we can create a virtual directory by making changes in the Project settings. I did the same thing as mentioned in the video but still I was not able to see the Virtual directory in IIS manager. But I was getting the popup that says "Virtual Directory created successfully." Where is it getting created? Any help? Screenshot of the project settings below. I even removed the port number and tried creating Virtual directory but I was not able to see the virtual directory in inetmgr even then.

[image]

Comment: This creates a record in the config file for your IIS Express.

Comment: Figured it out. Had to change the IIS Express drop down to Local IIS.After that, I got the virtual directory.